# PostgreSQL: Intersection entre polygons retorna linhas e pontos

Tags: postgresql

Estou trabalhando em uma consulta espacial e tenho duas tabelas com feições de GeometryType APENAS Polygon ou MultiPolygon:

TABELA ZONEAMENTO:

```sql
select ST_GeometryType (geom), count (*) 
    from    
        legislacao_urbanistica_municipal.prod_lu_zon_zoneamento
group by ST_GeometryType (geom)
```

Essa consulta me retorna:

> "ST_MultiPolygon"  "13"
>
> "ST_Polygon"   "606"

TABELA QUADRA

```sql
select ST_GeometryType (geom), count (*) 
    from    
        cadastro_tecnico_municipal.prod_ct_ctm_quadra_ctm
group by ST_GeometryType (geom)
```

Essa consulta me retorna:

> "ST_MultiPolygon"  "110"
>
> "ST_Polygon"   "17661"

Observem que só há Polygon ou MultiPolygon.

No entanto, quando dou um ST_Intersection, o meu retorno contém pontos, linhas e polígonos e multis.... De tudo! E isso está me atrapalhando num consulta posterior:

Essa é a consulta que faz a interseção:

```sql
create materialized view legislacao_urbanistica_municipal.lu_lei_7166_zoneamento_quadra_vw as
select  row_number() over (order by id_tipo_zoneamento) as id,
        ST_Intersection(ST_Multi(quadra.geom),ST_Multi(z_7166.geom)) as geom,
        z_7166.id_tipo_zoneamento
    from    legislacao_urbanistica_municipal.prod_lu_zon_zoneamento as z_7166,
            cadastro_tecnico_municipal.prod_ct_ctm_quadra_ctm as quadra
    where ST_Intersects (z_7166.geom , quadra.geom)
```

E o retorno dos Geometry Types dela:

```sql
select ST_GeometryType (geom), count (*) 
    from    
        legislacao_urbanistica_municipal.lu_lei_7166_zoneamento_quadra_vw
group by ST_GeometryType (geom)
```

> "ST_GeometryCollection"    "195"
>
> "ST_LineString"    "3"
>
> "ST_MultiLineString"   "41"
>
> "ST_MultiPoint"    "2"
>
> "ST_MultiPolygon"  "783"
>
> "ST_Point" "13"
>
> "ST_Polygon"   "18782"

O problema é que dessa tabela eu faço uma outra consulta de Intersection e, como ela tem GeometryCollection nela, o PGAdmin me dá erro:

```sql
SELECT  h.id_zona_homogenea_tgc, 
        z.id_tipo_zoneamento,
        z.sigla_zoneamento
    FROM    tributario.prod_tr_lim_zona_homogenea_tgc as h, 
            (
                select  a.id_tipo_zoneamento, 
                        b.sigla_zoneamento, 
                        a.geom 
                    from    legislacao_urbanistica_municipal.lu_lei_7166_zoneamento_quadra_vw a,
                            legislacao_urbanistica_municipal.prod_lu_zon_tipo_zoneamento b
                    where a.id_tipo_zoneamento = b.id_tipo_zoneamento
            ) as z
    where   ST_Intersects(h.geom,z.geom)
    group by h.id_zona_homogenea_tgc, z.id_tipo_zoneamento, z.sigla_zoneamento
    ORDER BY id_zona_homogenea_tgc
```

> ERROR:  ERRO:  Relate Operation called with a LWGEOMCOLLECTION type.  This is unsupported.
>   HINT:  Change argument 2: 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(POINT(612590.299990058 7794557.73136217),POLYGON((612588.6...
>   SQL state: XX000

Já tentei algumas soluções (Dump, cast, Multi), mas não tá rolando. Alguém sabe o motivo e alguma solução?